# fix error attempt to perform arithmetic (add) on string

Tags: lua, roblox

```
if (hit.Name == "Base") then return end
   hit:BreakJoints()
   if (hit.Anchored == true) then hit.Anchored = false end
   wait(.5)
   for i=1, 10 do
        hit.Transparency = hit.Transparency + 0.1
        wait(0.2)
    end
    print("removing" + hit:GetFullName()) <---- here
    hit:remove()
end
connection = script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

but i got " attempt to perform arithmetic (add) on string error "in line 10 can you fix this error pls?

Comment: please read the Lua manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `hit:GetFullName()` is returning a `string`, in Lua, we use two dots `..` to concatenate two strings instead of the plus `+`:

```lua
print("removing " .. hit:GetFullName())
```